# Infinite loop using 'while' and 'continue'

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, continue

List song contains the lines of "Baby Shark". Output the lyrics of song line by line inside the loop, but skip the lines do do, do do do do.

```
song = ['Baby shark', 'do do, do do do do',
  'Baby shark', 'do do, do do do do',
  'Baby shark', 'do do, do do do do',
  'Baby shark',
  'Mama shark', 'do do, do do do do',
  'Mama shark', 'do do, do do do do',
  'Mama shark', 'do do, do do do do',
  'Mama shark']

    songs = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(song):
      if song[i] in ('d',',', 'o')
        i += 1
        continue
      songs += song[i]
      i+= 1
    print(songs)
```

This is the loop I wrote, but it's throwing a syntax error for my "if song[i] in ('d', ',','o') line of code.

I know the content is silly but this was one of the questions and I am really struggling with loops.

Comment: You're missing the `:` at the end of the `if` line.

Comment: Also your `if` condition is wrong. None of the list elements are single characters, so they'll never be in a list of single characters.

Comment: Don't use a `while` loop for this. Use `for phrase in song:`

Comment: (What @Barmar said) And note that `song[i]` is one of the full strings in `song`, so `song[0]` is "Baby shark".  Thus your corrected `if` statement will never match anything.  Perhaps you meant `song[i][0]` - the first letter of the `ith` element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Python's error messages put quite a bit of effort into trying to highlight the problem. In this case, you should notice that the error message doesn't just highlight the `if song[i] in ('d', ',','o')` line, but *points at* the end (using a `^` symbol). That's because there's something either missing or extra there.

Comment: so if I change the if condition to ('do do, do do do do') it's returning

Comment: Also, please try to title questions in a way that describes the actual problem. If there is a syntax error, then do not say there is an infinite loop.

Comment: the song is wrongly written, it should be `baby shark, doo-doo, doo-doo-doo-doo` source: https://open.spotify.com/track/5ygDXis42ncn6kYG14lEVG?si=ae8984c39bfc4590

Answer (score 0):

your if statement was

`if song[i] in ('d', ',', 'o'):`

here you check if all the song is one of these letters.

Ex:
checking if `'Baby shark'` is one of these `('d', ',', 'o')`

---

So I changed the if statement a little to do something similar

`if 'do do' in song[i]:`

it checks if the sub-string `'do do'` is in the `song` string

Ex:
checking if `'do do'` is in `'do do, do do do do'`

```py
song = [
    'Baby shark',
    'do do, do do do do',
    'Baby shark',
    'do do, do do do do',
    'Baby shark',
    'do do, do do do do',
    'Baby shark',
    'Mama shark',
    'do do, do do do do',
    'Mama shark',
    'do do, do do do do',
    'Mama shark',
    'do do, do do do do',
    'Mama shark'
]

# removed indentation
songs = ''

i = 0

while i < len(song):
    # edited the if statement and added the ":"
    if 'do do' in song[i]:
        i += 1
        continue
    songs += song[i]
    i+= 1
print(songs)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included a commentary about what was wrong, and why you fixed it the way you did.

Comment: This would be simpler if you didn't have to repeat the `i += 1` code.

Comment: @Barmar -> I didn't want to change the concept of his code

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice that he has this same logic.